# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Messaging#requestPermission on channel firebase_messaging

Tags: firebase, flutter

```
final NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission();
```

I am getting this error when calling requestPermission() method of firebase messaging.

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Messaging#requestPermission on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging)
> E/flutter ( 7180): #0      convertPlatformException (package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:13:5)
> E/flutter ( 7180): #1      MethodChannelFirebaseMessaging.requestPermission (package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_messaging.dart:286:13)
> E/flutter ( 7180):

In build.gradle I implemented
'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'

implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.0')

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had the same issue. Fixed it updating to the last version:

```
firebase_core: ^1.10.0
firebase_messaging: ^11.1.0
```

Comment: yeah, it is working

Comment: You are the man!

Comment: This is what's working for me.

Comment: Thats not work for me

Comment: How is this a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Use the latest versions of below packages

firebase_core

> https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core/versions

firebase_messaging

> https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/versions

Answer (score 1):

Terminate the current running session.

Do `flutter pub get` in your terminal

Then run again.

Comment: I try it . but it still can't work

Comment: What version for firebase messaging are You using?

Comment: firebase_messaging: ^10.0.8

Answer (score 0):

remove onBackgroundmessage from the firebase configure, it's a temporary solution but it works for older firebase packages

Answer (score 0):

Update it to the latest version

```
firebase_core_platform_interface: ^4.7.0
firebase_messaging: ^14.6.3
```

If the problem persists, try to add the permissions in the **AndroidManifest file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. firebase_messaging: ^14.2.0
2. Run pub get
3. [Stop 'main.dart'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybGMk.png)
4. Then Hot Restart